# Images of different shapes touching each other

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is cut into different pieces. Assume an image that is physically cut into puzzle shaped pieces.

Using HTML and CSS only, how can I align all the pieces of the puzzle so that it looks like a single image after assembling?

I have actual separate pieces, not using something like image maps or sprites.

Edit:
The problem is not an actual puzzle, it is slightly different. I want the ability for 1 or more of the pieces to be changed, without affecting the look of the whole.

Edit to the problem:
An addition to the problem is that some of the images might have more than 1 "pieces" with blanks in the middle.
So, for example,

ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP

is the original image, with each letter as separate pieces. It is possible that

A C
  G
is 1 piece, with blanks/transparents for the other places, and not even a complete one.

Meaning:
A0C0
00G0
0000
0000

where 0 is the blank place.

The above figure will not exist. It will be

A0C
00G

only.

So basically we are looking at overlays. The original positioning of the default pieces would have the images with lowest z-index so that every piece that will be shown will have a higher index.

Sorry for the problem to sound so complex.

Comment: Post some code and explain what the use is for. Why not combine all the images into one image using an image editing software and then just use the one image? Read up on `float`ing elements. One way to accomplish this with purely css is to have a fixed position parent div and all the images within the parent div should be floated, although it seems like using css for this is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `position:relative` **to parent div** and `position:absolute` **to images** inside that.

Then play with **top, left, bottom and right** properties to place them.

Add `height` and `width` to the **parent div**; which should equal to or greater than the dimension of combined image pieces.

Below is **Demo**

```css
.wrapper{ float:left; position:relative; width:400px; height:400;}

.img-1{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:200px; height:100px; background:#888;}
.img-2{position:absolute; top:0; left:200px; width:200px; height:200px; background:#666;}
.img-3{position:absolute; top:100px; left:0; width:150px; height:100px; background:#333;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-1">img1</div>
  <div class="img-2">img2</div>
  <div class="img-3">img3</div><!-- you have to put img tag here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can this answer be updated based on the new requirement?